# Is a continuous function $\mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ on a compact set Riemann integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus

From the standpoint of the higher dimensional Riemann Integral:

For a general bounded set, $S$, that is not a rectangle, the convention is to integrate $f$ over $S$ by first subsuming $S$ within some rectangle $Q$ and then integrating $f_{S}$ (the characteristic function of $f$ with respect to $S$; ie $f(x) = f$ for $x \in S$ and $f(x) = 0$ for $x \not \in S$) over $Q$.

As a consequence, $f_{S}$ is integrable over this rectangle $iff$ the set $E$ of points $x_{0} \in \delta(S)$ for which $$\lim_{x \to x_{0}}f(x) \not = 0$$ is measure zero.

Here $\delta(S)$ is the border of $S$.

That is,

$$m(\{x_{0} \in \delta(S) | \lim_{x \to x_{0}}f(x) \not = 0 \}) = 0$$

A continuous function may, thus, fail to be integrable over a compact set, if $E$ is not measure zero. Could someone propose an example of such an instance?

Comment: What is the meaning of $f_S$ -- is it the restriction of $f$ to the set $S$? Also what is $\delta(S)$?

Comment: To clarify here: You're talking about Riemann integration. So you might want to think about just the function $f=1$ on $S$. But you want to make the boundary of $S$ *not* have measure $0$. Can you design such a set $S$?

Comment: $f_S (x) = \begin{cases} f(x), & x\in S \\ 0, & x\notin S\end{cases}$, as a function on an enclosing rectangle.

Comment: I believe that the boundary of a compact set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ always has measure 0.  This is certainly true if your set is a manifold.

Comment: @RobArthan: I was just trying to switch the focus from the function to the set $S$ itself, which could be troublesome. If the boundary of $S$ has measure $0$, then the function $f$ becomes irrelevant, does it not, in trying to violate the criterion?

Comment: @ChocolateAndCheese: Yes, if the boundary is a finite union of $C^1$ submanifolds, then of course it has measure $0$. But it's definitely *not* true for an arbitrary compact set.

Comment: @coffeemath Sorry, I should have introduced my notation. I've done so now.

Comment: @TedShifrin The standard (and only) example that comes to my mind of a set $S$ whose boundary is not measure zero is $\mathbb{Q}^{n} \subseteq [a,b]^{n}$. In this case, however, $S$ is not compact, since $S$ is not closed. So I don't have any examples :C

Comment: You want to thicken up that set in a way to leave plenty of stuff uncovered. But Gio67 has given you the solution :)

Comment: @TedShifrin Do you have an example of a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ whose boundary has nonzero measure?  I'm having trouble coming up with an example.

Comment: Well, offhand, one construction is to take [a simple closed curve of positive measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osgood_curve) in the plane. Since it is a Jordan curve, it bounds a topological disk. The union of the disk and its boundary will be such a compact set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider an enumeration $\{q_{n}\}_{n}$ of the sets of points in $(0,1)^{N}$
with rational coordinates $\mathbb{R}^{N}$, that is, $(0,1)^{N}\cap
\mathbb{Q}^{N}=\{q_{n}:\,n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Fix $\varepsilon>0$ and for each
$n$ consider the ball $B(q_{n},r_{n})$, where $r_{n}\leq\frac{\varepsilon
}{2^{n}}$ and $r_{n}>0$ is so small that $B(q_{n},r_{n})\subseteq(0,1)^{N}$.
Let $U:=\bigcup_{n=`1}^{\infty}B(q_{n},r_{n})$. Denoting by $\mathcal{L}^{N}$
the Lebesgue measure, we have that
$$
\mathcal{L}^{N}(U)\leq\sum_{n=`1}^{\infty}\mathcal{L}^{N}(B(q_{n}%
,r_{n}))=\alpha_{N}\sum_{n=`1}^{\infty}r_{n}^{N}\leq\alpha_{N}\sum
_{n=`1}^{\infty}\frac{\varepsilon^{N}}{2^{Nn}}\leq\alpha_{N}\varepsilon^{N}<1
$$
provided $\varepsilon>0$ is sufficiently small. On the other hand, by the
density of the rationals, the closure of $U$ is $[0,1]^{N}$. Thus the boundary
of $U$, $S=\partial U=[0,1]^{N}\setminus U$ has positive Lebesgue measure.
Taking $f=1$, we have that
$$
f_{S}(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}
[c]{ll}%
1 & \text{if }x\in S,\\
0 & \text{if }x\in U.
\end{array}
\right.
$$
It follows that $f_{S}$ is discontinuos at every point of $S$ and so
it cannot be Riemann integrable in $[0,1]^{N}$.

Comment: Isn't $\delta(S) = [0,1]^{n}$ since every point in $S$ has a neighborhood intersecting both $int(S)$ and $int(S^{C})$? Also, $S$ is not closed in your example, so it can't be compact (I think).

Comment: If you want $S$ compact, call $U$ the union of the balls and $S=[0,1]^N\setminus U$. Then $S$ is compact.

Comment: As to your first question, no, the union of the balls is open so any point in this union is an interior point and not on the boundary

Comment: If you construct $S$ to make it compact ($S = [0,1]^{N} - U$), then the function $1$ on $S$ is no longer continuous. Is that true?

Comment: You take f=1 which is continuous. But then $f_S$ is not. I edited my question. Hope it is clear now.